# Could not create role AWSCodePipelineServiceRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to auto-deploy my static websites Github changes to my s3 bucket and when I went to create the pipeline, it threw a "Could not create role AWSCodePipelineServiceRole" error.

My github has permissions setup correctly. The repo name, bucket name, and object key are correct.

Has anyone ever encountered this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind the issue was that your IAM user (the user you are logged in as) is restricted to create role with service role name 'AWSCodePipelineServiceRole'.

In order to provide IAM user permission to create role with service role name ‘AWSCodePipeline*’ e.g. ‘AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-us-east-1-test’, you need to attach the below policy to your IAM user:

```
{

    "Version": "2012-10-17", 
    "Statement": [
        {    
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",    
            "Action": "iam:CreateRole",    
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AWSCodePipeline*"    
        }    
    ]    
}
```

Comment: Not enough. the policy JSON code above is a copy/paste from another forum on the Internet, and didn't solve the issue for me. Plus, the previous step of the CodePipeline wizard asked me to check the box if I authorised CodePipeline to create a role. It's called delegation, therefore my on user's privs should not be involved.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by:

1. Step 1: adding the deployment user I was logged on as into a
   `Deployers` Group, to which I granted the `IAMFullAccess` policy.
2. Step 2: I successfully created the pipeline by following the same
   steps as indicated by the AWS tutorial.
3. Step 3: once create, I
   reversed engineered the group and single policy attached to it that
   the wizard created. It showed a really long policy that you can't
   really invent. The IAM section being:

   "Statement": [
   {
   "Action": [
   "iam:PassRole"
   ],
   "Resource": "*",

I am just concerned that the `Deployers` group I created now has `IAMFullAccess`...

Also, I found that if you are logged as an admin, and add privileges to an IAM user, that user may not immediately enjoy these new privileges. I decided to log out and log back in to commit them. Maybe there is a lighter way, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try couple of things:

1. Try to create the IAM role with different name (e.g. AWSCodePipelineServiceRole2020).
2. Give the pipeline a different name and keep the role name as it is
   (auto generated) by pipline.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add these 4 policies to get the CodePipeline creation issue fixed.

```
            "iam:CreateRole",
            "iam:CreatePolicy",
            "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
            "iam:PassRole"
```